# How do I query a GeometryCollection in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I am trying to run a mongoldb query on a GEOjson collection of points and polygons but I'm struggling. I am new to GEOjson and Mongodb and haven't been able to find any examples on how to do this via google search and S.O. search so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on my issue.

I have created a 2DSphere index on geometry.coordinates - not sure if that's correct or not.

My overall objective is to return all points within the current map view and add both the point and the polygon associated to the map. I am using Leaflet.js and understand how to add to the map, but I can't figure out the query on Mongodb to get the results.

Just looking to find out if my GEOjson is correct and maybe an example on how I would perform the search on my GeometryCollection and get the point using $geowithin and then get the associated polygon.

Here's an example of my GEOjson-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5709722f4044ccc4b8291651"),
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries" : [
        {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                -105.960805584616,
                39.4671896545181
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "Polygon",
            "coordinates" : [
                [
                    [
                        -105.96110187372227,
                        39.463449804295806
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.96602244670311,
                        39.462956063632134
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.96577627486317,
                        39.46671592928652
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.96553007974012,
                        39.470475771657675
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.96047434857059,
                        39.47089761421853
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.95541854755197,
                        39.471319247231634
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.95579990086372,
                        39.46763141937862
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.95618125417559,
                        39.463943568242485
                    ],
                    [
                        -105.96110187372227,
                        39.463449804295806
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
},
    "properties" : {
        "processed" : "Yes"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your index is incorrect. It should be on `"geometry"` which is the top level field in which the `GeometryCollection` is defined. That said, by the sound of this you are probably better off "splitting" the `GeometryCollection` items and storing each "individually" in it's own MongoDB document. A query on the collection in it's present form will **only** return the "document", and not the specific entries that match conditions within. There are ways to do that, but they are not a straightforward as putting the objects in their own documents and are actually quite complex. And not as performant.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the insight. I like your suggestion of breaking them into separate documents. I'll give that a try. Also, I tried creating the index on "geometry" but received the error 'Can't extract geo keys'. I'll keep trying and maybe reformat the doc. Thanks again.